# Gradle delete set of files

Tags: gradle

I am trying to delete set of files as i was in many [examples](http://fileTree(dir:%20'app/styles'%20,%20include:%20'**/*.css'))

```
task deleteApkFiles(type: Delete) << {
  println("-------------------------------------")
  println("---------------DELETE---------------")
  println("-------------------------------------")
  def files = fileTree(dir: '.', include: '**/*.apk').files
  delete fileTree(dir: '.', include: '**/*.apk')
  println(files)

}
```

Print shows me only files which i want to delte

```
[app-minAPI16-prod-release.apk, app-minAPI16-prod-release.apk, app-minAPI16-beta-debug.apk]
```

But `delete` does not delets them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to delete files in foreach loop

```
def files = fileTree(dir: '.', include: '**/*.apk').files
files.each {File f -> delete f}
```

Comment: This will delete files during configuration of the gradle build, which is probably A Bad Thing to do

Answer (score 1):

just remove `<<`

and it will work. i don't know why =)

```
task deleteApkFiles(type: Delete)  {
  println("-------------------------------------")
  println("---------------DELETE---------------")
  println("-------------------------------------")
  delete fileTree(dir: '.', include: '**/*.apk')
}
```

Comment: It works because `<<` adds an action to the task and configuring `delete` in action is too late to make it.

Comment: `<<` is deprecated and is going to be removed in 5.0.

Comment: It works, because that's how [you're supposed to do it](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete.html)

Comment: i added do last, at i need to execute task at specific point, not automaticly